# What is the meaning of the index argument in glDrawElements?

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, indexing, graphics

There are two OpenGL documentation pages which have slightly different descriptions of the "index" parameter of the glDrawElements function. On www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/ it says:

```
indices
    Specifies a pointer to the location where the indices are stored.
```

And on www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3 it says:

```
indices
    Specifies a byte offset (cast to a pointer type) into the buffer bound 
    to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER to start reading indices from. If no buffer
    is bound, specifies a pointer to the location where the indices are stored.
```

I am on Windows by the way, using OpenGL 4+.

So I've copied my index array into the element buffer object I created, the indices pointer argument I need to supply is the offset in bytes of the first index? So if I want to start drawing at index 3, the argument would be 2 * sizeof(GLuint), cast as a pointer?

I actually went to the effort of creating an EBO for this, but from the looks of it it says that if no EBO is bound the pointer points straight to the location where the indices are, not the EBO. Am I right that this means it will point to your array on the system RAM? (EDIT: I just realised this doesn't make sense, if the pointer is at 0x00000008 it can't go to that address in system memory.) And if so, does it then copy the index array to the graphics card each time in order to be able to use it? Thanks.

Comment: indices: Base address of your indices array. You should just supply the base address. The third parameter specifies the size of each indices. It's typically set to GL_UNSIGNED_INT

Comment: @Asesh Thanks, I think I get it. But it says if an element buffer object isn't bound the index pointer points directly to where the index array is stored. That makes me think system RAM, but that doesn't make sense, doesn't it always get the index from the element buffer object on the GPU? So confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per OpenGL 4.5, core profile, reading from client memory is unsupported (§10.3.10 OpenGL 4.5 core spec):

> **DrawElements**, **DrawRangeElements**, and **DrawElementsInstanced** source their  indices  from the  buffer  object  whose  name  is  bound  to
>   `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, using  their *indices* parameters  as  offsets  into  the  buffer  object  in  the  same  fashion  as  described  in  section  10.3.9. [...] If zero is bound to `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, the result of these drawing commands is undefined.

So your approach of creating an EBO is correct. Except if your 0th index is located at offset zero then the 3rd index is located at offset `3*sizeof(type)`.

As for your second quotation: in the older OpenGL versions you could pass a pointer to the client memory (in your process virtual address space, not the physical address) and leave `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` unbound.

Comment: @ybundaloBill First index is at offset 0, second index is at offset 4, third index is at offset 8, isn't it?

Comment: If you count from one then yes. I suggest you start counting from zero, then it will be less confusing: nth index at offset `n*sizeof(type)`. Note that the `type` is not required to be `GLuint`, you can use 8-bit or 16-bit indices too.